How do I make two different table styles?
EDIT: I've updated this post with some of people's suggestions. I still can't get the coding to work right, though.
I'm trying to create a document with two distinct table styles (basically dialogue boxes): One type of table has a black background with white border and white text. And the other table type is going to have a white background (no border) with black text. (The document as a whole is white text on a black background.) But when I try to create these two table styles, it just takes one over the other; either both table types have white background or a black background. In my current example, both end up having white background with white text--literally unreadable!
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <style>
    table.table1 td {
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        border: 6px solid white;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 250px;
        font-family: Consolas;
    }
    table.table2 td {
        background-color: white;
        color: black;
        width: 200px;
        font-size: 13px;
    }
    </style>

This is what I have for the body style:
<body style="background-color:black; color:white; font-family:Calibri">

What am I doing wrong? (I wish I could show the actual document itself, but I can't find a way to attach documents on this forum; the page is unpublished as yet.)

Please update the question to include a [mcve] as a runnable code snippet which demonstrates the problem you are describing.

Perhaps it's a typo?  You're missing a semi-colon in one of your style rules.

Please improve the indent in the code blocks

I've edited my post with some of your suggestions. I still can't get the coding to work. Side note: I really hate that you can get downvoted just for asking questions on here. And yes, at least one person has downvoted my post. I wish someone could undo that because it really affects my self-esteem, and is why I so rarely post on this forum; I never get it right. I swear I need a tutorial on how to post on this site, in addition to the actual problem I need help with!

The browser Inspector is good for finding the cause of these kind of bugs. It will show all the CSS rules being applied to a particular element. It could be some other CSS from another file overriding your styles. And +1 (for your self esteem)

You are overwriting the styles in your second block because you use a comma after table.table1 and table.table2.
Basically that is the same as just write two times td { ...... } - where the second block overwrites the first.
If you put a space between the table-class and td you make the td styles dependent of the prefix-classname of your table:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <style>
    table.table1 td {
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        border: 6px solid white;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 250px;
        font-family: Consolas;
    }
    ul {
        list-style-type: "* ";
    }
    table.table2 td {
        background-color: white;
        color: black;
        width: 200px;
        font-size: 13px
    }
    </style>

Tip: Move the inline styles of your body tag to your style-section as well.
EDIT:
I tested the code via Codepen and I don't know what exactly is not working for you. So here comes a code snippet you can test directly here - I added some styles to make clear that the styles make a difference.


body {
  background-color:black;
  color: red;
  font-family: times;
  font-size: 10px;
}

table.table1 td {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border: 6px solid white;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 250px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 14px;
}

table.table2 td {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: verdana;
}
<p>
  Content outside table
</p>
<table class="table1">
  <tr>
      <td>Content table1 cell 1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="table2">
  <tr>
      <td>Content table2 cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>



Every style-part (body, .table1 and .table2) reacts to the styles assigned.

Thanks for this. I tried inputting your suggestion, and it's a little bit better but not all the way there. The table1 table now looks exactly like the body, as if there's no table at all. Basically the body format has taken it over. I'm not sure how to fix this?
